# Correct use of $ne or $not in pymongo (unsupported projection option)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to write the following query in Mongo:

*Get all rows where `field` equals `var1` but/and not `var2`*

I have this:

```
db["mydb"].find(
    {"field": var1},
    {"field": {
        "$ne": var2}
    }
)
```

But it yields the error that `$ne` is an "unsupported projection option."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `$and` operator to combine requirements like this:

```
db["mydb"].find(
    {"$and": [
        {"field": var1},
        {"field": {
            "$ne": var2
        }}
    ]}
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the usage of `$and`, you can also fix it by using `{}` to combine the filters.

```
db["mydb"].find({
    "field": var1,
    "field": {"$ne": var2}
})
```